# Angular 5 this.route.paramap

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, contentful

Im trying to set a child route that takes in the id of an element Im pulling in from my contentful cms

so In my **main.module.ts**

```
RouterModule.forChild([
        {
            path: '',
            children: [
                { path: 'week-1', component: Week1Component },
                { path: 'week-1/:id', component: AssetPageComponent }
            ]
        }
    ])
```

then in my **week-1.component.html**

```
<div [routerLink]="['/week-1', item.sys.id]" class="program_card_inner_icon_{{item.fields.assetType}}"></div>
```

then in the recieving component **asset-page.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Entry } from 'contentful';
import { ContentfulService } from '../../../contentful.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-asset-page',
  templateUrl: './asset-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./asset-page.component.scss']
})
export class AssetPageComponent implements OnInit {
  programItem: Entry<any>;

  constructor(
    private contentfulService: ContentfulService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.contentfulService.getAsset(params.get('id')))
    .subscribe(programItem => this.programItem = programItem)
  }

}
```

then in my contentfulSerive.ts

```
// Get all the program items
  getProgramItems(query?: object): Promise<Entry<any>[]> {
    return this.cdaClient.getEntries(Object.assign({
      content_type: CONFIG.contentTypeIds.programItems
    }, query))
    .then(res => res.items);
  }
 // Get only the program items with specified week
 getWeekItems(week: number): Promise<Entry<any>[]> {
    return this.getProgramItems({'fields.week': week});
 }

  // Get program with certain id
  getAsset(id: string): Promise<Entry<any>[]> {
    return this.getProgramItems({'sys.id': id});
  }
```

which is how Ive read this should work but Im getting some errors and I dont know what they mean.. my tslint is saying [image] and in the console im getting

[image]

I havent really done anything like this before so Im not sure what Is going wrong, any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `then` is not used with Observables. `then` is used with Promises. As far as the other error, we may need to see what the `this.contentfulService.getProgramItems` expects as a parameter.

Comment: @R.Richards please see updated question

Comment: Okay, looks like what you are getting back from the service is an array, and what you have the local variable typed as is not an array. Try typing your local variable `this.programItem` as `Entry<any>[]` and see if that helps.

Comment: @R.Richards Sorry could you please specify what you mean where would i put that??

Comment: Sure. In your `AssetPageComponent` change this: `programItem: Entry<any>;` to this: `programItem: Entry<any>[];`

Comment: @R.Richards Thanks! this worked... I do have an issue though when I try to interpolate the data so for example {{programItem.fields.assetType}} i get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'assetType' of undefined
    at Object.eval` but If I use an `*ngFor` and say let item of asset and then do item.fields.assetType it works.. any idea what could be the problem??

Comment: Doesn't sound like a problem, really. You are getting an array of `Entry<any>` from your service call. You have to loop through that with `*ngFor`, or access an item in the array via the index, i.e. `this.programItem[0]`. Now that you have something you can work with, it is up to you to decide what the application does with it.

Comment: @A61NN5 Just curious - was the information in my answer enough to get your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate issues here. Both issues have to do with the return type of the `getAsset` method in the *contentfulService.ts* file.

The return type of `getAsset` is `Promise<Entry<any>[]>`, meaning that a call to this method will get you a `Promise`, which contains an `Array` of `Entry` types (which can contain anything apparently).

Your situation is a little complicated because you are ending up with a `Promise` inside of an `Observable`:

```
 this.route.paramMap // This is an Observable
   .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => 
     this.contentfulService.getAsset(params.get('id')) // This returns a Promise
   )
   .subscribe(programItem => this.programItem = programItem)
```

So you need some way to bring that `Promise` into `Observable` world...

You can do this using the [`fromPromise`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromPromise) operator or the [`from`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-from) operator.

```
this.route.paramMap
   .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
     const p: Promise<Entry<any>[]> = this.contentfulService.getAsset(params.get('id'));
     return Observable.from(p);
   })
```

So now you are mapping your `queryParam` to an emit-once `Observable` The [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) operator is doing quite a lot for you here by mapping from one observable (`route.paramMap`) to another observable, which is based on a promise. You can now use `subscribe` to observe the value emitted from the new observable:

```
this.route.paramMap
   .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
     const p: Promise<Entry<any>[]> = this.contentfulService.getAsset(params.get('id'));
     return Observable.from(p);
   })
   .subscribe(...)
```

I can't really tell you what to put in the `subscribe` block as it is dependent on your particular program. What I can tell you is that you are getting an *array* of `Entry<any>` (that's what the `[]` means). And currently you are trying to save an *array* of `Entry<any>` (`Entry<any>[]`) into a *single* `Entry<any>`.

You'll either need to change the type of your `programItem` property to `Entry<any>[]` or pick the element from the array that you want to save in the `programItem` property: e.g. `programItem[0]`. That's up to you.

Comment: my tslint gave me an error saying Cannot find name 'Observable'

Comment: You need to import it from rxjs - import Observable from ‘rxjs/Observable’, you will need to import the from operator from ‘rxjs/Observable/from’ or something similar as well.